# How to sum up values for specific names in each row?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sum, conditional-statements

I am new to SQL and was not able to solve the following problem: I've got a column of names [name]), a column of integer values that I wanna sum up ([Values]) and another column of integer values ([Day]). I want to sum up the values grouped by name for each day. So for example if there is a name "Chris" with value 4 on day 1 and there is another entry "Chris" with value 2 on day 3, I want to show the sum of chris on day_1 (4) and on day_2 (4+2=6).

As in the example above ("chris") I wanna sum them up, showing the sum for each name on each day (the sum from day 1 until day x).

I was only able to sum up the values for each name per day (see code below) but this is not what I am searching for since I need to keep the structure of the database. Therefore I need to show the sum for each value in every row in a further column.

```
select name, day,
sum(value) over (partition by name order by day) total
from tablename
```

There is a table below showing what I want to achieve.

[image: table]

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Would you please provide sample data and expected output, so we are sure of what exactly you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `sum()` window function:

```
select *,
  sum(value) over (partition by name order by day) SumValue,
  sum(value2) over (partition by name2 order by day) SumValue2
from tablename 
order by day
```

or:

```
select name, day, value, name2, value2,
  sum(value) over (partition by name order by day) SumValue,
  sum(value2) over (partition by name2 order by day) SumValue2
from (select *, row_number() over (order by day) rn from tablename) as t
order by rn
```

if you want to preserve the original sequence of the rows.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=abbbb9cbd9022ed18b936aae669f77b5).
 
Results:

```
> name  | day | value | name2 | value2 | SumValue | SumValue2
> :---- | --: | ----: | :---- | -----: | -------: | --------:
> Chris |   1 |     2 | Paul  |      5 |        2 |         5
> Alice |   1 |     5 | Ken   |      4 |        5 |         4
> Paul  |   2 |     8 | Alice |      1 |        8 |         1
> Ken   |   2 |     4 | Chris |      2 |        4 |         2
> Alice |   3 |     3 | Ken   |      3 |        8 |         7
> Chris |   3 |     6 | Paul  |      0 |        8 |         5
```

Comment: This is excatly what I have searched for! Great, you helped me a lot. Thank you so much!

Comment: One last stupid question (I am still learning the basiscs actually): when summing up the values in "SumValue" and "SumValue2" there no columns created? When I try to calculate with this columns names it says that this column name is invalid and I cannot see any column name in the object explorer of SSMS. Do I have tá create a further column?

Comment: Unaccepting the answer is not the way to draw attention.

Comment: Sorry I was not sure if you get noticed in case of a closed question

Comment: This is a select statement. It does not create columns in the table. The calculations return query (virtual) columns. If you need these columns to make other calculations you must include this query in the sql statement, give it  an alias say `t` and refer to the columns like `t.SumValue` and `t.SumValue2`..